# Windows Azure - Include a WCF service in a virtual directory of a web role

Tags: windows, wcf, azure, cloud

Is it possible to have a wcf service role live in a virtual directory (or the equivalent not sure if that word is the appropriate one for Azure) of a web role on Azure.

For example:

```
www.mydomain.com                  <- contains the web role or website
www.mydomain.com/myservice.svc    <- contains the WCF service
```

I've seen people suggest that you can change the config to allow for virtual directories, however I have RDPed into both VMs and they appear not to share the same files on disk.

I am Azure newbie, please forgive the terminology. But is it possible to do what I am wanting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web site and a WCF service can be accessed using the URLs you listed above if they are both in the same web role. You will get the URLs you describe above if you do the following:

1. Create a new cloud project in Visual Studio, specifying a Windows Azure Cloud Service.
2. At the prompt, add an MVC web role.
3. At the next prompt, select Internet Application and press OK.
4. When the project is created, right click on the MVC project and choose Add --> New Item --> WCF Service.
5. Press F5. The default ASP.NET MVC home page will show up. Then navigate to `http://yourlocalhostaddress/Service1.svc`. You'll see the typical "You have created a service" landing page for a new WCF service.

Comment: Thanks, @seanost, this solution works for me, though I'd be curious how you would do it, if you still wanted to host your service in a separate web role instance?

Comment: The short answer is that you can do it if you're OK with your WCF service endpoint having a different port designation. That's how Azure designates different web roles for the same domain, by port. For example, create a new project, add a web role, then add another web role to the project. For the second web role, add a WCF service (like the instructions above). When you press F5, two browser windows will appear, one in this format: `http://127.0.0.1`, and the other with `http://127.0.0.1:8080`. You can access the service only by using `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Service1.svc`.